# Accessing the values inside a map in Kotlin

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, kotlin, key-value

I'm having difficulty accessing the values in this dictionary/map I built inside of this animals object:

```
object Animals {
var animalInfo = mutableMapOf<String,Any>()
init {
    animalInfo["Animal"] = mutableListOf("description" to "Large Mammal", "name" to "Elephant", "highlights" to arrayListOf("Long Trunk", "Flappy Ears", "Ivory Tusks"))
    }
}
```

Swift being my first language I tried to access the values like this but without the use of optional binding:

```
 val dataDict = Animals.animalInfo
        val animal = dataDict["Animal"]
        println(animal["description"])
        println(animal["name"])
        println(animal["highLights"])
```

All the println lines have an unresolved reference error. How do I  correctly access the values in a mutableMapOf()?

Comment: Still can't compile. `animalInfo` and `moduleInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var animalInfo = mutableMapOf<String,Any>()
```

into

```
var animalInfo = mutableMapOf<String,MutableMap<String, out Any>>()
```

and change

```
val module = dataDict["Animal"]
```

into

```
val module = dataDict["Animal"]!!
```

and change `mutableListOf` into `mutableMapOf` should resolve this (3 changes in total).

Comment: Wait I've found it too, give me a minute